# Thread freezes program

Tags: python, multithreading, class

I have a function:

```
def threaded(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        thread.start()
        return thread
    return wrapper
```

And a class:

```
class someclass(somestuff):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(thing)
        .
        .
        .

    @threaded
    def start_thread(self):
        while True:
            self.update_watchers()

    def update_watchers(self):
        .
        .
        .

    def otherfunctions(self):
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

And in my main:

```
obj = someclass()
handle = obj.start_thread()
handle.join()
```

Now, if I take the `while` loop out of `start_thread`, everything works fine. I suspect I am using forever-threads long (a forever thread is a thread that runs as long as the program is running, of course).

As an FYI, this program occupies a list. Not a Python list, a GUI list. It looks into a file that is constantly being updated. `update_watchers()` updates the watchers I have running over the file, extracts information when (for example) the program is paused (which is one of the several reasons why I need a thread).

Can someone explain to me what is going on? It keeps breaking when I get to `handle`'s definition. I know I must be using the While loop wrong and there is a correct way to do it. I need start_thread to run all the time because I need update_watchers to be running all the time.

I cant really post more code than that.

Thank you

Edit: `threaded` function taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846332/python-threading-inside-a-class)

Comment: You posted too much code and at the same time not enough. Extract a minimal but complete example, as it stands your question is off-topic.

Comment: Do you want to run what's inside `while True:` and than stop that thread somewhere in the code?
If you want that thread to work from start to end of program you should consider interrupting this thread or making something like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36499538/4984268)

Comment: @Iluvatar Thanks! That's exactly what I was gonna look up next!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `handle.join()` waits until the thread represented by `handle` completes.  Since it has a `while True` it will never complete, and thus the join will never terminate.
You almost certainly don't want to `join` on a thread you intend to run forever.
Solving your problem is likely as simple as removing `handle.join()`.

Comment: Well... there you go. Thanks man