# A clean API for making a function call threaded in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I would like to call a function in a thread. Calling it with 
the conventional API looks like:

```
from threading import Thread
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(int(1e8),1)

Thread(target=np.savez_compressed, args=('/tmp/values.a', dict(a=a))).start()
```

I was wondering if there is a pythonic was of making this threaded call with a cleaner API, without defining a  function which is specific for `np.savez_compressed`.

E.g. something in the style of (pseudo-code):

```
@make_threaded
np.savez_compressed('/tmp/values.a', dict(a=a))
```

Unfortunately decorators can only be applied to function definitions, so the pseudo-code above is not legal.

**EDIT**: I am not looking specifically for a decorator API. Rather, a cleaner way to make a function call threaded

Comment: Decorators don't work like that. They go on top of functions or classes - not function calls

Comment: I’m sure that’s possible. Have you tried anything yet? Have you ever written a decorator yourself?

Comment: I am not looking specifically for a decorator API. Rather, a cleaner way to make a function call threaded

Comment: @quamrana I looked on decorators and context-managers but I could not find anything that is satisfying.

Comment: What do you mean with "clean"? Why isn't the first snippet "clean"?

Comment: Are you aware of [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module provides a more high-level API for using threads or processes for individual operations.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()
executor.submit(np.savez_compressed, '/tmp/values.a', dict(a=a))
```

If you don't want the entire Executor API, you can define your own helper to run a function in a thread.

```
def threaded(call, *args, **kwargs):
    """Execute ``call(*args, **kwargs)`` in a thread"""
    thread = threading.Thread(target=call, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    thread.start()
    return thread

threaded(np.savez_compressed, '/tmp/values.a', dict(a=a))
```

Answer (score 0):

OP here:

Another solution I found was by using decorators with the decorators "classic" API:

```
from threading import Thread

call_threaded(np.savez_compressed)('/tmp/values.a', dict(a=a))

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/19846691/2476373
def call_threaded(fn):        
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        thread = Thread(target=fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        thread.start()
        return thread
    return wrapper
```