# Using Thread.join() method with threads that inside inside a class

Tags: python, multithreading, wrapper

I am solving this question from LeetCode: [1116. Print Zero Even Odd](https://leetcode.com/problems/print-zero-even-odd/)

I am running this [solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/print-zero-even-odd/discuss/809929/Clean-Python-or-Semaphore-Coordination) in VS Code with my own main function to understand the issue in depth.

After reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846332/python-threading-inside-a-class) and the suggested solutions. In addition to reading this [explanation](https://gist.github.com/awesomebytes/0483e65e0884f05fb95e314c4f2b3db8).

I added this code to the code from the solution:

```
from threading import Semaphore
import threading

def threaded(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        threading.Thread(target=fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs).start()
    return wrapper
```

and before those functions from the question I added: `@threaded`

I added a `printNumber` function and `main` function to run it on VS Code.

```
def printNumber(num):
    print(num, end="")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = ZeroEvenOdd(7)
    handle = a.zero(printNumber)
    handle = a.even(printNumber)
    handle = a.odd(printNumber)
```

Running this code gives me a correct answer but I do not get a new line printed in the terminal after that, I mean for input `7` in my main function, the output is: `01020304050607`**hostname** and not what I want it to be:

`01020304050607`

**hostname**

So, I added `print("\n")` in the main and I saw that I get a random output like:

```
0102

0304050607
```

or

```
0

1020304050607
```

still without a new line in the end.

When I try to use the join function `handle.join()` then I get the error:

> Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no
> attribute 'join'

I tried to do this:

```
handle1 = a.zero(printNumber)
handle2 = a.even(printNumber)
handle3 = a.odd(printNumber)
handle1.join()
handle2.join()
handle3.join()
```

Still got the same error.
Where in the code should I do the waiting until the threads will terminate?

Thanks.

Comment: Voting to close because there is not enough information in the question. The answer below explains the meaning of the error message, but OP still seems to be confused, and has not provided enough of a code example to illustrate what is confusing them.

Comment: @SolomonSlow But I posted the code I relied on, which is the solution in the link and in addition I posted the code I wrote to run this solution in VS Code.
I can post the whole code, that it will be the union of the two above.

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to use...`handle.join()`...I get the error: "...'NoneType' object has no attribute, 'join'

The error message means that the value of `handle` was `None` at the point in your program where your code tried to call `handle.join()`. There is no `join()` operation available on the `None` value.

You probably wanted to `join()` a *thread* (i.e., the object returned by `Threading.thread(...)`.  For a single thread, you could do this:

```py
t = Threading.thread(...)
t.start()
   ...
t.join()
```

Your program creates *three* threads, so you won't be able to just use a single variable `t`.  You could use three separate variables, or you could create a list, or...  I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: I edited the question.
I tried it before by creating three different variables. It did not help me.

Comment: @Asaf, Why do you think that `a.zero(...)`, `a.even(...)`, and `a.odd(...)` will return thread objects? The code for those functions is not shown in your question, so there's no way for me to guess what you were thinking there. But it certainly looks as if your `wrapper(...)` function creates a thread, starts the thread, and then _throws away the reference to the new thread object._ There's no way you can `join()` a thread if you don't have a reference to the thread object.

Comment: the functions: `zero(...), even(...), odd(...)` are the same functions from the solution I attached in the link in question.
Why the `wrapper(...)` don't return the thread object?
Thanks.

Comment: @Asaf Those functions are empty on the page to which you linked: They do nothing, and they return `None`. They are [_skeletons_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeleton_(computer_programming)), that you are supposed to fill in with your own code to make them do something.

Comment: I mean from this solution: https://leetcode.com/problems/print-zero-even-odd/discuss/809929/Clean-Python-or-Semaphore-Coordination
I have attached this to my question.